# Using Bootstrap 4 login form with django UserForm

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, bootstrap-4

Hey i want to use Bootstrap's login view with my UserForm but came up with few problems.

This is the template:

```
<body class="text-center">
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <img class="mb-4" src="../../assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="form.id_username" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" id="form.id_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="form.id_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="form.id_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
</form>
</body>
```

My UserForm:
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password =forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =['username','password']
```

and my views.py:

```
class LoginView(View):
    template_name = 'accounts/login_form.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
    def post(self, request):
        form =self.form_class(request.POST)
        user = authenticate(username =request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('travel:main')
            form=self.form_class(None)
            return render(request, self.template_name,{'form':form})
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('travel:main')
```

I basically want to authenticate the input from `<input type="text" id="form.id_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>` against the form.username and input from `<input type="password" id="form.id_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>` against the form.password. Do you know where is the problem ?

Comment: If i understand you you want to add placeholder in your field and others html attributs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix syntax errors in above case. In forms we have to provide names to input/text/radio fields.

## forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
  username = forms.EmailField()

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields =['username','password']
```

## template.html

```
<body class="text-center">
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <img class="mb-4" src="../../assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
        <label for="form.id_username" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" id="form.id_username" class="form-control" name="{{ form.username.html_name}}" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="form.id_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="form.id_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required name="{{ form.password.html_name}}">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
</form>
</body>
```